# uninitialized constant Contact::Csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

NOTE: In my application.rb file I have required both `csv` and `iconv`.

I am building a Ruby on Rails app to import .xls and .csv files into a database of contacts. I am using Rails Cast #396 as my guild, but it has some issues since I am using Rails 4.

I have implemented (to the best of my ability) the ability to upload .csv, .xls, and .xlsx files. However, when I select a .csv file for upload, I get the following error and stack trace:

```
uninitialized constant Contact::Csv

Rails.root: C:/workspace/contactually-lite

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/contact.rb:18:in `open_spreadsheet'
app/models/contact.rb:6:in `import'
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:5:in `import'
```

Here is my contact.rb file:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      contact = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      contact.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      contact.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
      else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my `contact_controller.rb` file:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def import
    Contact.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Contacts imported."
  end

  # the following code taken from RailsCast 396, may be useful
  # def index
  #   @products = Product.order(:name)
  #   respond_to do |format|
  #     format.html
  #     format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
  #     format.xls # { send_data @products.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
  #   end
  # end

  # GET /contacts
  # GET /contacts.json
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
  end

  # GET /contacts/1
  # GET /contacts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contacts/new
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  # GET /contacts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contacts
  # POST /contacts.json
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contacts/1
  # DELETE /contacts/1.json
  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email_address)
    end
end
```

Here is my `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # generated by scaffold
  # resources :contacts

  # taken from railscast 396
  resources :contacts do
    collection { post :import }
  end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'contacts#index'

end
```

UPDATE:

Here is my index.html.erb view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Contacts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email address</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= contact.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= contact.last_name %></td>
        <td><%= contact.email_address %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', contact %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Contact', new_contact_path %>

<h2>Import Contacts</h2>

<%= form_tag import_contacts_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>It should be `CSV` instead of `Csv`.</s>

<s>`when ".csv" then CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)`</s>

***Update:***

Seems like the you are using `roo` gem as stated in the railscast. If so as per [***this***](https://sunilsharma3639.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/importing-csv-and-excel-in-rails-4-and-ruby-2-0/) link, the code should look like below for ***Rails 4***

```
when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
```

Comment: It's Csv.new in the source code for rails cast 396, and it works fine. Also when I change my code to CSV.new, Rubymine gives me a pretty red line under my code saying that I am passing too many arguments to the constructor .

Comment: Also, when I exclude enough arguments to make the constructor actually fire, it creates a host of other issues. I think Csv is the correct class.

Comment: @FluffyKittens It is `CSV`. And try when ".csv" then `CSV.parse(file.path, :headers=>true)` instead of `when ".csv" then CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)`

Comment: When I try `CSV` I get the following error and stack trace: `NoMethodError in ContactsController#import
undefined method `row' for #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:1>

Rails.root: C:/workspace/contactually-lite

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/contact.rb:7:in `import'
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:5:in `import'`

Comment: You need to take a look at the source code for the Rails Cast, because it's definitely Csv.new in that code. Has the Csv class been renamed to CSV in a later version of Ruby? I realize that `CSV` is indeed a Ruby class, I can see it in the API. But it's not the class which was used in the rails cast which I am following, and the code doesn't work with `CSV.new`

Comment: In the RailsCast it looks like the author has created a class called `Csv`, which is not the same class that `require "csv"` accesses. You can see [in the ASCIICast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) the author calls `CSV.foreach`, which *is* the class you get from `require "csv"`. Perhaps it's you who should take a closer look at the RailsCast, @FluffyKittens.

Comment: Wow thanks @Jordan! And Pavan thank you for your answer, I missed the Roo gem entirely. Howvere, when I fully qualify using `Roo:Csv` I get `uninitialized constant Roo::Csv`. This must be because of my missing `Csv` class.

Comment: @FluffyKittens Try `Roo::CSV` instead of `Roo::Csv`

Comment: Well, good news. That seems to work, but a different error occurs. I'm trying to debug it myself, but here it is in case your interested: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: C:/workspace/contactually-lite

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/contact.rb:7:in 'import'
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:5:in 'import' `

Comment: @FluffyKittens Looks likes `params[:file]` is nil. Try debugging it.

Comment: It is definitely nil but I'm not sure why

Comment: @FluffyKittens Posting your view code would be helpful.

Comment: Sure @Pavan, I have updated my OP with the code from my `index.html.erb` code.

Comment: @Jordan, I have watched the ASCII cast Rails cast and no class named Csv is created at any point. Did you see something that I missed?

Comment: For the record, @Jordan, the `Csv` class in the Roo gem was renamed to `CSV` in the time period between the creation of this rails cast and now. It was not a separate class created by Ryan Bates. The code is working, and while the answer did not completely solve my problem ,it certainly shed some light on the situation and genuinely helped me understand the issue.